# Why am I getting an SQL error when trying to insert a null?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ok when trying to execute the following insert I'm getting an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '2, 3, 4, 5)' at line 1

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO applicants (id_file, address_file, photo, transcript, essay1, essay2) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       $passport_file,
                       $address_file,
                       $photo_file,
                       $transcript_file,
                       $essay1_file,
                       $essay2_file);

  mysqli_select_db($STCi, $database_STC);
  $Result1 = mysqli_query($STCi, $insertSQL) or die(mysql_error($STCi));
```

Those variables are being set using the following code

```
    $_FILES['id_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK?$passport_file=filesDB('id_file'):$passport_file = NULL;
    $_FILES['address_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK?$address_file = filesDB('address_file'):$address_file = NULL;
    $_FILES['photo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK?$photo_file = filesDB('photo'):$photo_file = NULL;
    $_FILES['transcript']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK?$transcript_file = filesDB('transcript'):$transcript_file = NULL;
    $_FILES['essay1']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK?$essay1_file = filesDB('essay1'):$essay1_file = NULL;
    $_FILES['essay2']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK?$essay2_file = filesDB('essay2'):$essay2_file = NULL;
```

filesDB is my own function I'm running to rename the uploaded files and move them into the correct locations and any that are running through that are fine.  The problem comes out with 'address_file' as it is an optional file and whenever nothing is uploaded for it I get the error.

So basically MySQL is throwing an error when I'm trying to insert NULL, or am I missing something obvious?

```
CREATE TABLE `applicants` (
  `applicant_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_file` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_file` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_change` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `transcript` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `english_result` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `essay1` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `essay2` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `stage` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'New',
  `date_applied` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`applicant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: paste table structure here

Comment: @diavolic there is the create statement for the table.

Comment: take the first step to debug by printing $insertSQL on screen

Comment: replace $passport_file = NULL to $passport_file = "NULL" and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing an `sprintf`, and inserting 'NULL', meaning you have a PHP varaible that is NULL.

Your SQL query should look like this after the `sprintf`:

```
INSERT INTO applicants (id_file, address_file, photo, transcript, essay1, essay2) 
VALUES (null, 2,3,4,5,6)"
```

but it looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO applicants (id_file, address_file, photo, transcript, essay1, essay2) 
VALUES ( , 2,3,4,5,6)"
```

And that's an error.

To fix this, you could actually insert the string `null` here (if you insert it without `'`, it will not be seen as a string, as you are not using prepared statements). So you query would look like so:

```
    INSERT INTO applicants (id_file, address_file, photo, transcript, essay1, essay2) 
VALUES ( null , 2,3,4,5,6)"
```

Do this by not assiging `NULL` to the variable, but just assign `'null'`. Verify by first echoing your query. It should have the `null` in it wihtout any quotes.

A better method is to use actual prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: You can verify by echo-ing your `insertSQL` .

Comment: thank you very much for your swift and helpful response :)

Answer (score 2):

use a prepared stamement instead of manually creating a query with sprintf:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($STCi, "INSERT INTO applicants 
                (id_file, address_file, photo, transcript, essay1, essay2) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss",
                           $passport_file,
                           $address_file,
                           $photo_file,
                           $transcript_file,
                           $essay1_file,
                           $essay2_file);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysql_error($STCi));;
}
```

Comment: Agreed but the actual insert is a LOT larger than this and I don't want to rewrite the entire thing just to add these file uploads.

Comment: @AaronHarker At least remember to quote the variables before using them in the query [mysqli.real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the php null value and the mysql null value - they arent the same thing. I think you want something like:

$_FILES['id_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK?$passport_file=filesDB('id_file'):$passport_file = 'NULL';

Note I have quoted the "null". This will put a text null into the sql statement, which will then be interpreted as the keyword 'null' in mysql.
If you leave the php assignment as the value null then a sort of blanky thing is passed to mysql, when it wants the text string 'null' :)

Comment: concocting SQL queries from PHP variables directly is a very bad idea. therefore, although technically you are right, it should never be done like that

Comment: indeed, but he needed to know that he was trying to pass a php null to a mysql null and they are not the same thing.
Not even escaping the values... :shudders:

Answer (score -1):

in order to insert null values you should be using prepared statements

```
$stmt = $STCi->prepare("INSERT INTO applicants (id_file, address_file, photo, transcript, essay1, essay2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss",
                       $passport_file,
                       $address_file,
                       $photo_file,
                       $transcript_file,
                       $essay1_file,
                       $essay2_file);
$stmt->execute();
```